# Flutter - How to check user role before redirecting using GetX

Tags: flutter, dart, authorization, flutter-getx

```
   void onReady() {
    super.onReady();
    firebaseUser = Rx<User?>(auth.currentUser);
    firebaseUser.bindStream(auth.userChanges());

    //GetX function that listens to user state changes
    ever(firebaseUser, _setInitialScreen);
  }

    //gets called immediately after sign up, giving no chance to check user role
   _setInitialScreen(User? user) async {
    if (user == null) {
      Get.offAll(() => AuthenticationScreen());
    } 

      //Need to check user role here (before going to else)
      else {
          if (userModel.value.role == "fieldOwner") {
            Get.offAll(() => FieldOwnerHome(user: user));
          } else {
            Get.offAll(() => HomeScreen(user: user));
          }
    }
  }
```

The control runs to the Get.offAll() before anything else can be called.

```
  void signUp() async {
    showLoading();
    try {
      await auth
          .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
              email: email.text.trim(), password: password.text.trim())
          .then((result) async {
        String? _userId = result.user?.uid;
        await _addUserToFirestore(_userId);

       //function to get user and check role
        await _initializeUserModel(_userId);

        _clearControllers();
      });
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint(e.toString());
      Get.snackbar(
        "Sign Up Failed",
        e.toString(),
        snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM,
      );
      dismissLoading();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to move Code from `onReady()` to `onInit()`

Answer (score 0):

your code is pretty much correct. just put this below code in your main.dart file.

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp().then(
    (value) => Get.put(
      AuthController(),
    ),
  );
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

Also make sure to create instance for your AuthController, just like this

```
class AuthController extends GetxController {
  // instance
  static AuthController get instance => Get.find();
  // user
  late Rx<User?> user;
  // auth
  FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  // firestore
  FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  .....
```